# Sequelize: only the last few rows are updated

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I have an array of (few thousands of) data object that I need to insert or update depending on a condition. A simple `upsert()` method is implemented in my model class.

**Implementation**

```
    csv.upsert = async function (values, condition) {
    let obj = await csv.findOne({ where: condition });
    
    if (obj) {
        // update
        console.log("existing record updated")
        return await obj.update(values);
    } else {
        // insert
        console.log("new record inserted")
        return await csv.create(values);
    }
    
}
```

This upsert method is then used, where I loop through the array of objects to insert or update them in db.

**Usage**

```
try {           
    await models.sequelize.authenticate();          
    await models.sequelize.sync();          
    let dataToBeInserted = getArrayOfDatatoInsert();            
    dataToBeInserted.map(async function (data) {                
        let condition = {
            'categorygroup': data.categorygroup,
            'category': data.category,
            'country': data.country,
            'city': data.city
        };
        await csvModel.upsert(data, condition);
    })
    // await restofthestuff();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
}
```

For test I took a dataset where all of my data needs to be updated.

When I run this method:

I can see in the (along with sequelize log turned on) log that `"existing record updated"` message is printed for each and every record that exists which is desired output. Only the last few (30) data gets updated in the db. Where as it works for csv.create(values)

~ How can I update all the records and obviously not just the last 30 data, any help's appreciated. ~

> EDIT: Apparently I got this to work by using `csv.update(values, {where: condition})` instead of using `obj.update(values)`.
>
> New question: I didn't look further into the sequelize's update method but is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the commented code below, your log is after your return and so will never be executed.

Also you were not using await in an async function, so either don't make it async or use await.

```
csv.upsert = async function (values, condition) {
    const obj = await csv.findOne({ where: condition });
    // you can await here, no need for then as you are in an async function

    if (obj) { // update
        // you need to log before your return condition
        console.log("existing record updated")
        return obj.update(values);
        // since we return here, the rest of the code will not be executed
        // you can skip the use of else
    }
    // we are in this part of the code only if object is falsy

    // insert
    console.log("new record inserted")
    return csv.create(values);
}
```

You could also use `Promise.all` to ensure all the upsert are done:

```
await Promise.all(dataToBeInserted.map(async function (data) {
    let condition = {
        'categorygroup': data.categorygroup,
        'category': data.category,
        'country': data.country,
        'city': data.city
    };
    await csvModel.upsert(data, condition);
}))
```

this will also ensure that if an error occur it gets catched by your try / catch

Maybe that will help you find what's causing the unexpected behaviours.

Comment: >As detailed in the commented code below, your log is after your return and so will never be executed.

Yes true on this, I did have console.log before update. I wrote it below accidentally when typing for the question.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I've actually already tried the suggested solutions. I also tried exact solution that you suggested with Promise.all. Still no luck though.

Comment: so apparently csv.update (instead of obj.update) works just fine.

Comment: Ah yes nice catch, I didn't notice you were doing the update from the result value !
But it's wierd that you didn't get an error saying `.update` is not a function in that case...